# Postgresql : single quotes causes to error in queries

Tags: python, postgresql, bytea

I have a query which update image on to Postgresql, So i came across problem with single and double quotes , below is how my query should look like

```
UPDATE public."tb_Student"
SET "Image" = bytea_import('C:/Users/Alice/Wonderland.jpg') 
WHERE "Code" = '763902';
```

and here is how i added in my Python code :

```
UpdateQuery = 'UPDATE public."tb_Studennt" SET "Image" = bytea_import('''+str(directory)+str(filename)+') 
WHERE "Code"='''+str(content)+''
```

But there is problem of single quote and when i print Updatequery it comes like

```
UPDATE public."tb_Student" SET "ImageAdded" = bytea_import(C:/Users/Alice/Wonderland.jpg) WHERE "ImageName"= 763902.0
```

missing single quote for both data inside bytea_import and 763902.0

can anyone please help me solve this .

Comment: What connector package are you using?

Comment: Am using Python & Postgresql @snakecharmerb

Comment: I mean what connector package - psycopg2, pg8000...?